# Pandas restacking repeated values to columns

Tags: python, pandas

The below DataFrame needs to be restacked, so that I have all values for each region on one line. In the below example the new df would only have 3 lines, one for each region. The corresponding values would then expand along multiple columns.

The regions may vary, and there may be more than 3. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
>>> a
Out[26]: 
Area value 
0 EUROPE 47
1 ASIA 51
2 AMERICAS 37
3 EUROPE 39
4 ASIA 22
5 AMERICAS 24
```

Desired output:

```
Europe 47 39
Asia 51 22
Americas 37 24
```

The values should be spread among different columns

Comment: Sorry can you edit your question with your desired output, for instance does `df.groupby('Area').apply(list)` do what you want?

Comment: It might if it output values. But with this syntax I only get Europe [Area, values] and no actual values

Comment: Sorry missed the col accessor should be `df.groupby('Area')['value'].apply(list)`, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'Area' and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) `list`:

```
In [75]:
df.groupby('Area')['value'].apply(list).reset_index()

Out[75]:
       Area     value
0  AMERICAS  [37, 24]
1      ASIA  [51, 22]
2    EUROPE  [47, 39]
```

This will handle a variable number of values

If you want to split the values out you can call `apply` and pass `pd.Series` ctor:

```
In [90]:
df1 = df.groupby('Area')['value'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()
df1[['val1', 'val2']] = df1['value'].apply(pd.Series)
df1

Out[90]:
       Area     value  val1  val2
0  AMERICAS  [37, 24]    37    24
1      ASIA  [51, 22]    51    22
2    EUROPE  [47, 39]    47    39
```

**EDIT**

For a variable number of columns you can't assign upfront if you don't know what the max number of values will be but you can still use the above:

```
In [94]:
import io
import pandas as pd

t="""index Area  value
0    EUROPE     47
1      ASIA     51
2  AMERICAS     37
3    EUROPE     39
4      ASIA     22
5  AMERICAS     24
5  AMERICAS     50"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
df

Out[94]:
   index      Area  value
0      0    EUROPE     47
1      1      ASIA     51
2      2  AMERICAS     37
3      3    EUROPE     39
4      4      ASIA     22
5      5  AMERICAS     24
6      5  AMERICAS     50

In [99]:
df1 = df.groupby('Area')['value'].apply(list).reset_index()
df1

Out[99]:
       Area         value
0  AMERICAS  [37, 24, 50]
1      ASIA      [51, 22]
2    EUROPE      [47, 39]

In [102]:
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df1['value'].apply(pd.Series).fillna(0)], axis=1)
df1

Out[102]:
       Area         value   0   1   2
0  AMERICAS  [37, 24, 50]  37  24  50
1      ASIA      [51, 22]  51  22   0
2    EUROPE      [47, 39]  47  39   0
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what the question asked for. Now a slight variation so that the data can be plotted in multiple bar plot: how can I transform it so that the areas are columns and each value is in a row? For that the data should not be in a list I assume but spread across multiple columns so it can be transposed.

Comment: Sorry if you have another question then please post another question, incrementing your requirements is not a good use of SO, also you need to show what your desired plot should look like given that you don't have numeric values for your Areas

Comment: I clarified in the question that the values should be spread among different columns.

Comment: What happens when you have a non uniform number of values? You expect separate columns for each value?

Comment: @Nicolas so if "AMERICAS" had `[37, 24, 99]` as a value, the other two would have two leading zeros?

Comment: Yes that's right. But don't worry about that. In my case they are uniform.

Comment: It's pretty good now. Only thing that can be improved is that the amount of columns is variable.

Comment: That's difficult as you'd have to find the max number of elements and create the required number of columns

Comment: In my case I fortunately had this. I can then simply do columns=range(maxelements) and it all works. cheers