# Pandas reshaping repeating rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reshape a dataframe with repeating rows. The data comes from a csv file where blocks of data are repeated.

As an example:

```
    Name      1st    2nd
0 Value1      a1     b1 
1 Value2      a2     b2 
2 Value3      a3     b3
3 Value1      a4     b4
4 Value2      a5     b5
5 Value3      a6     b6
```

Shall be reshaped into:

```
Name     1st 2nd 3rd 4th
Value1   a1  b1  a4  b4
Value2   a2  b2  a5  b5
Value3   a3  b3  a6  b6
```

Do you have any suggestions how to do this?
I've already watched this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082712/pandas-restacking-repeated-values-to-columns), however I can not see how to translate this approach to my problem, where there is more than one column right of the column the groupby is worked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to combine your two columns into one, [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get the new column labels, and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to do the reshaping:

```
# Stack the 1st and 2nd columns, and use cumcount to get the new column labels.
df = df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame()
df['new_col'] = df.groupby(level='Name').cumcount()

# Perform a pivot to get the desired shape.
df = df.pivot(columns='new_col', values=0)

# Formatting.
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
```

The resulting output:

```
     Name   0   1   2   3
0  Value1  a1  b1  a4  b4
1  Value2  a2  b2  a5  b5
2  Value3  a3  b3  a6  b6
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dataframe with repeated values of df after grouping by Name and merge that df with the original.

```
df1 = df.groupby('Name')['1st', '2nd'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1]).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['Name', '3rd', '4th']
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name']).merge(df1, on = 'Name')
```

You get

```
    Name    1st 2nd 3rd 4th
0   Value1  a1  b1  a4  b4
1   Value2  a2  b2  a5  b5
2   Value3  a3  b3  a6  b6
```